# Can you convert VectorDrawable pathData into a Path object

Tags: android, vector

Is it possible to pull the `pathData` out of a `VectorDrawable` and convert it into a `Path` object?

I want to create a custom `ViewOutlineProvider` and give it an arbitrary shape to clip and cast shadows from.  If there's a way to directly use a `VectorDrawable` that'd be even better.

thanks,
ndh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "Android Can you convert [`VectorDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable) **->** [pathData](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/understanding-vectordrawable-pathdata-commands-in-android-d56a6054610e) into a
>   android.graphics.[`Path`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path)".

## Introduction

We need to:

- Parse [`VectorDrawables`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable) from XML to find [pathData](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/understanding-vectordrawable-pathdata-commands-in-android-d56a6054610e)
- Inflate [`VectorDrawables`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable) from XML to a `View` class (or sub-class, ImageView etc...)
- convert [pathData](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/understanding-vectordrawable-pathdata-commands-in-android-d56a6054610e) to [`Path`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path) class (using [`android.util.PathParser`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/17e64ffd852f8fe23b8e2e2ff1b62ee742af17a6/core/java/android/util/PathParser.java))

> There is [VectorMaster](https://github.com/harjot-oberai/VectorMaster) in the `github` which can do *all the work*
>   for you.

Just add the following dependency in your app's `build.gradle` (see example app included):

```
dependencies {
      compile 'com.sdsmdg.harjot:vectormaster:1.1.3'
}
```

Here is an Image of **my test app** which uses it:
[image]

## Setup

Here's a Vector to work with (pathData) ...res\drawable\**ic_heart.xml**:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:name="outline"
        android:pathData="M20.84,4.61a5.5,5.5 0,0 0,-7.78 0L12,5.67l-1.06,-1.06a5.5,5.5 0,0 0,-7.78 7.78l1.06,1.06L12,21.23l7.78,-7.78 1.06,-1.06a5.5,5.5 0,0 0,0 -7.78z"
        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:strokeColor="#5D5D5D"
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:strokeWidth="2"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"/>
</vector>
```

Here is a `VectorMasterView` in our layout:

...res\layout\**activity_main**:

```
<com.sdsmdg.harjot.vectormaster.VectorMasterView
    android:id="@+id/heart_vector"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:scaleX="0.8"
    android:scaleY="0.8"
    app:vector_src="@drawable/ic_heart" />
```

## Code

Setup the `Vector` in `onCreate`:

```
//normal stuff
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//Inflate the `Vector`
VectorMasterView vmHeartVector = (VectorMasterView) findViewById(R.id.heart_vector);

// find the correct path using name
PathModel outline = vmHeartVector.getPathModelByName("outline");

String pathData   = outline.getPathData();// this is our pathData
Path   path       = outline.getPath();    // this is our path object;
```

Some links:
[`Vector drawables overview`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources), 
[`Path`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path),
[pathData](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/understanding-vectordrawable-pathdata-commands-in-android-d56a6054610e),
[`VectorDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable),
[`AnimatedVectorDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable),
 [`VectorDrawableCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat),
[`AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat).

Comment: For those who is looking for pathData->Path conversion, here it is: https://github.com/harjot-oberai/VectorMaster/tree/master/vectormaster/src/main/java/com/sdsmdg/harjot/vectormaster/utilities/parser

Comment: @Jon-Goodwin i want to draw that pathData to canvas , if a single vector have multiple pathData i want to draw each pathData to canvas one by one because i want to allow drag/fly each pathdata when i click . How to do that can you please help me?