# Stroke Color in Vector Drawable Not Working Correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-vectordrawable

I have created a vector drawable from an SVG file which I am displaying in an `ImageView`within a layout using the Asset Studio in Android Studio.  In one of the paths I am defining a stroke with a strokeColor of `#FF50BEFF`.  But for some reason when I use that color, the stroke is not appearing.  It does appear correctly for certain colors, like black. Below is the xml for the vector drawable.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:width="78dp"
    android:height="120dp"
    android:viewportWidth="78"
    android:viewportHeight="120">
  <path
      android:pathData="M8,111a31,9 0,1 0,62 0a31,9 0,1 0,-62 0z"
      android:fillColor="#000"
      android:fillAlpha=".08"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M39,109c24.667,-33.044 37,-56.377 37,-70C76,18.565 59.435,2 39,2S2,18.565 2,39c0,13.623 12.333,36.956 37,70zM39,54c7.732,0 14,-6.268 14,-14s-6.268,-14 -14,-14 -14,6.268 -14,14 6.268,14 14,14z"
      android:strokeLineJoin="round"
      android:strokeWidth="4"
      android:strokeColor="#FF50BEFF"
      android:fillType="evenOdd">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
      <gradient 
          android:startY="39.25312"
          android:startX="39"
          android:endY="40.31242"
          android:endX="39"
          android:type="linear">
        <item android:offset="0" android:color="#FF50BEFF"/>
        <item android:offset="1" android:color="#FF4BAFFF"/>
      </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
  </path>
</vector>
```

The correct rendering of the drawable is

[image]

But instead is shows up in the `ImageView` as

[image]

Note the missing stroke in the lighter shade of blue along the lower half of the image and below the center circle.

Also, here is the xml file in which vector drawable appears.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white100">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drive_case_list_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drive_case_list_empty_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drive_case_list_content_marker_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_location" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/drive_case_list_content_marker_image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/drive_case_list_empty_title_text"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black87"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The vector drawable does appear correctly in Android Studio, so the problem seems to be how it is rendered within the app.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It has to do with the API level of the device you load your app to. I'm guessing it is less than 24 ?

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your response.  Actually, my phone is API level 24, and I just tried with an emulator running API level 28, and I see the same issue.

Comment: At any rate, do you know specifically what the problem is, and what workaround I can employ, aside of course from going back to using PNG images?

Comment: OK, thanks a lot, I will, and good luck with your move!

Comment: I had a look at your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45568938/can-you-convert-vectordrawable-pathdata-into-a-path-object/50394674#50394674.  ```VectorMaster``` looked promising, but unfortunately seems it doesn't handle a gradient fillColor which is in my ```Vector Drawable```.  I also don't think the issue is necessarily with backward compatibility, as it still doesn't render correctly in API Level 28.  I'm suspecting an Android bug or unsupported issue with rendering ```Vector Drawables```.

Comment: Yes, I think your right, something in the back of my mind says *"unsupported issue"*. There are a lots of links to Android docs, worth a read. But if in `API29` they `implemented` the `gradient ` you would still need `backward compatibility` for a while at least (until everyone upgrades). On  `backward compatibility` they are quite tardy. I'm sure they are ways around this, but use `.png` until then. `VectorMaster` is now unsupported for the reason that Android were implementing vectors faster than they could maintain it. Why not raise an issue with Google https://issuetracker.google.com ?

Comment: As a side note you **must** move to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) is the open-source project that the Android team uses to develop, test, package, version and release libraries within `Jetpack. AndroidX` is a **major** improvement to the original `Android Support Library`. ... You can update `AndroidX` libraries in your project independently. (none of this **v4 v7**...) nonsense required anymore).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201352/discussion-between-peter-jacobs-and-jon-goodwin).